# Android's RelativeLayout Unit Test setup

Tags: android

i'm trying to write an unit test for my Android's RelativeLayout. Currently, my testcode setup is as follow:

```
public class SampleRelativeLayoutTest extends AndroidTestCase {

private ViewGroup testView;

private ImageView icon;
private TextView  title;


@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    // inflate the layout
    final Context context = getContext();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    testView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_layout,
            null);
    // manually measure and layout
    testView.measure(500, 500);
    testView.layout(0, 0, 500, 500);
    // init variables
    icon = (ImageView) testView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    title = (TextView) testView.findViewById(R.id.title);
}
```

However, I encountered NullPointerException with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:427)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
at com.dqminh.test.view.SampleRelativeLayoutTest.setUp(SampleRelativeLayoutTest.java:33)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

What should I change in my setUp() code to make the test run properly ?

Comment: This worked like a charm for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086510/1293704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a copy of the Android source, but not sure if it's the same as what you're on (or maybe for this class it doesn't matter).  The exception is a NullPointerException at line 427 of RelativeLayout inside the onMeasure method.  That line in the version I have is the first access of mLayoutParams instance variable in the onMeasure method.  Is it possible you forgot to add the layout_width and layout_height params in your xml layout or something like that?

Comment: Thanks, indeed i missed the layout params.

After adding:
   testView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500,500));
the code runs properly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also works if you wrap your RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout. and pass the Linearlayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this an works:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(500,500);
testView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
testView.layout(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is that : you have a circular dependency between the size of the `RelativeLayout` and the position of its children. For example, you have a `RelativeLayout` whose height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and a child set to `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`.

Below is the annotation of `RelativeLayout`:

> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in
>   relation to each other or to the parent. For the sake of efficiency,
>   the relations between views are evaluated in one pass, so if view Y is
>   dependent on the position of view X, make sure the view X comes first
>   in the layout.

Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the `RelativeLayout` and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a `RelativeLayout` whose height is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and a child set to `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`.

Also see `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` for the layout attributes.