# measure() doesnt work properly with dynamic layouts and textView - Android

Tags: android, dynamic, bitmap, textview, measure

I want to convert a RelativeLaout view into a Bitmap. I've tried another answers and different options without success.
My XML View is kind of:

```
----RelativeLayout
-------ImageView
-------TextView
```

Every ones have wrap_content measures.

As i need several bitmaps of the view, im inflating it this way:

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.localviewlayout, null);

ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgPlace);
img.setImageBitmap(MyDynamicBitmap);

TextView txt1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
txt1.setText(MyDynamicText);
return v;
```

After that :

```
//in measure() i get a nullpointerException on RelativeLayout.onMeasure().I also have tried //with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
v.draw(new Canvas(b));
Paint p = new Paint();
myMainCanvas.drawBitmap(b, myPointX, myPointY, p);
```

The  content of textView  of the RelativeLayout is dynamic, so i cant know the width or height of the text. 
Besides of the exception, if i manually set enough size on the measure function (insted of 0), my dynamic text doesnt display entirely. 
I hope you can help me because right now, im stuck. Thank youuu

Answer (score 22):

Try adding

```
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

before calling `measure()`. Does that fix the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Had the same issue as the OP and adding the setLayoutParams from this post fixed the null pointer exception.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!you saved me!